# Callbacks in Fastai

Tags: callback, pytorch, fast-ai

I am working on a deep learning project in Fastai and wish to use EarlyStoppingCallback with ReduceLROnPlateauCallback in it. Read [callbacks.fastai](https://docs.fast.ai/callbacks.tracker.html#ReduceLROnPlateauCallback.on_train_begin) but struggling to understand how to implement both and couldn't find any relevant example. Any help would be appreciated.

```
learn = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet50, metrics = [accuracy,quadratic_kappa])
learn.fit(50,2e-6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I normally do it is this way....

First create the learner Object

```
    learn = Learner(data, 
                    model, 
                    loss_func=...., 
                    opt_func=...., 
                    metrics=..... )

    learn.unfreeze()
```

Then you call any callbacks on your fit_one_cycle

```
    learn.fit_one_cycle(16, 
                        max_lr=1e-3, 
                        div_factor=100,
                        pct_start=0.0, 
                        callbacks = [SaveModelCallback(learn,
                                     name=f'model',monitor='kappa_score')])
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can also do like this-:

```
from fastai.callbacks import *
from fastai.callback import Callback
from fastai.vision import partial

learner = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet50, metrics=[accuracy], pretrained=True, callback_fns=[partial(EarlyStoppingCallback, monitor='valid_loss', min_delta=0.01, patience=3)])

# or 

learner = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet101, metrics=[accuracy], pretrained=True, callbacks=EarlyStoppingCallback(monitor='valid_loss', min_delta=0.01, patience=3))


learner.fit(150)

# it will stop if "valid_loss" will not decrease (patience=3)
```